# JPA query using domain object Spring mvc jpa rest

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest, jpa

I want to know if its possible to build a jpa query using domain object.

For example:

```
       @Entity
       public class User {
       private String firstname;
       private String lastname;
       private String email;
    }
```

In real the object has much more fields. I receive a valid json string of this object. But not all fields are filled.

For example I get only filled firstname:

```
    {"firstname":"Peter","lastname":"","email":""}
```

This JSON gets deserialized to the User object

And now I want to make a search only using the object with the received parameter. The result should be all User with the firstname Peter.

The question is is it possible to give only the object to the query?

Thanks for inputs

---

**EDIT 1**

Thanks for the help until now. I found a solution to search for Contracts using the Entity. In this solution I post some updated values of contract and other methods.

The json look now like this:

```
contract = {fromDate:moment($('#datepickerVon').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY'), endDate:moment($('#datepickerVon').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY'), Season: {
          season: "SO14"}, name: {name: "peter"}, category:{category:"SomeString"}};

          console.log(contract);
      $.ajax({
          url:'/contracts/search/',
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          mimeType: 'application/json',
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify(contract),
          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          }
          });
```

The Controller receives like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> getVertagFromSearch(@RequestBody String json, UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder){
    Contract contract = contract.fromJsonToContract(json);
    List<Contract> contractList = Contract.findAllContractsPerContract(contract);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(Contract.toJsonArray(contractList), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

the deserialization is here:

```
public static contract fromJsonToContract(String json) {
    return new JSONDeserializer<Contract>().use(Calendar.class, new CalendarTransformer("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")).use(null, Contract.class).deserialize(json);
}
```

And here the transaction method.

```
 @Transactional
public static List<Contract> findAllContractsPerContract(Contract contract) {
    EntityManager e = entityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    Session session = e.unwrap(Session.class);
    Example contractExample = Example.create(contract);
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Contract.class).add(contractExample);
    List<Contract> list = c.list();
    return list;
}
```

With this example I get results. The question is now, is it possible to add some criteria to the sql like "bigger or less" or "like". Because at the moment it seems all criteria are searched with "equals".

Thanks

Comment: Check out Hibernate By Example http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-query-example-qbe. It's Hibernate specific that has no equivalent in JPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help until now. I found a solution to search for Contracts using the Entity. In this solution I post some updated values of contract and other methods.

The json look now like this:

```
contract = {fromDate:moment($('#datepickerVon').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY'), endDate:moment($('#datepickerVon').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY'), Season: {
          season: "SO14"}, name: {name: "peter"}, category:{category:"SomeString"}};

          console.log(contract);
      $.ajax({
          url:'/contracts/search/',
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          mimeType: 'application/json',
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify(contract),
          success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          }
          });
```

The Controller receives like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> getVertagFromSearch(@RequestBody String json, UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder){
    Contract contract = contract.fromJsonToContract(json);
    List<Contract> contractList = Contract.findAllContractsPerContract(contract);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(Contract.toJsonArray(contractList), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

the deserialization is here:

```
public static contract fromJsonToContract(String json) {
    return new JSONDeserializer<Contract>().use(Calendar.class, new CalendarTransformer("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")).use(null, Contract.class).deserialize(json);
}
```

And here the transaction method.

```
 @Transactional
public static List<Contract> findAllContractsPerContract(Contract contract) {
    EntityManager e = entityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    Session session = e.unwrap(Session.class);
    Example contractExample = Example.create(contract);
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Contract.class).add(contractExample);
    List<Contract> list = c.list();
    return list;
}
```

With this example I get results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you probably wouldnt get any result. What will happen is that the jpa provider (in this case hibernate) will detect the type is Entity object and does a comparison based on the @Id of the entity you are supplying, which i guess in this case will have a null id.

You will definitely have to do something like:

```
 @Entity
   @NamedQuery(name="User.findByFirstName", query="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.firstName = :firstName")
   public class User {
       private String firstname;
       private String lastname;
       private String email;
    }
```

And then on your session bean

```
public class UserBean{
     public List<User> findUsers(User user){
        return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("User.findByFirstName")
                .setParameter("firstName", user.getFirstName())
                .getResultList();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is what I have at the moment. My thinking was to avoid to write all the parameters. Yes you are right, in my real app the object @Id will be null. But can you post the way how it could work even I get no result? thanks